# Gmail Api Compose and send email with multiple attachment

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, gmail-api, email-attachments

My code for generating the email is mention below in #php #laravel

```
        $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $mixedBoundaryString = 'MixedBoundaryString';
        $relatedBoundaryString = 'RelatedBoundaryString';
        $alternativeBoundaryString = 'AlternativeBoundaryString';
        $subject = $request['subject'];
        $to = $request['to'];
        $message_text = $request['contentText'];
        $request['cc'] = str_replace(" ", "", $request['cc']);
        $cc_tmp = explode(';', $request['cc']);
        $cc = implode(", ", $cc_tmp);
        $request['bcc'] = str_replace(" ", "", $request['bcc']);
        $bcc_tmp = explode(';', $request['bcc']);
        $bcc = implode(", ", $bcc_tmp);
        $stripTagsMessageText = strip_tags($message_text);
        $raw = "To: {$to}
Cc: {$cc}
Bcc: {$bcc}
Subject: {$subject}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$mixedBoundaryString}\"

--{$mixedBoundaryString}
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"{$relatedBoundaryString}\"

--{$relatedBoundaryString}
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"{$alternativeBoundaryString}\"

--{$alternativeBoundaryString}
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

{$stripTagsMessageText}

--{$alternativeBoundaryString}
Content-Type: text/html;charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

{$message_text}

--{$alternativeBoundaryString}--
";
        if (isset($request['attachments']) && count($request['attachments']) > 0) {
            foreach ($request['attachments'] as $attachment) {
                if (!is_null($attachment)) {
                    $location = public_path() . '/email_attachments/sent/';
                    $filename = str_random(20) . '-' . $attachment->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file_location = $attachment->move($location, $filename);
                    $mimetype = $attachment->getClientMimeType();
                    $attachmentName = $attachment->getClientOriginalName();
                    $base64Attachement = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($location . $filename)), 76, "\n");
                    $raw .= "
--{$relatedBoundaryString}
Content-Type: {$mimetype};name=\"{$attachmentName}\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=\"{$attachmentName}\"
Content-ID: <{$to}>

{$base64Attachement}";
                }
            }
        }
        $raw .= "
--{$relatedBoundaryString}--

--{$mixedBoundaryString}--";
        $message->setRaw($this->base64url_encode($raw));
        return $message;
```

It gives the below content if I print preview  the data before base64url_encode

```
To: divya.deltatech@gmail.com
Cc: soniya.deltatech@gmail.com
Bcc: divya@divyashr.com.np
Subject: Multiple Attachment
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MixedBoundaryString"

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="RelatedBoundaryString"

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="AlternativeBoundaryString"

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain;charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Dear All,I’m writing to resign from my position as Web Developer, effective August 20, 2019.I’ve recently decided to go back to school, and my program starts in early September. I’m tendering my resignation now so that I can be as helpful as possible to you during the transition.I’ve truly enjoyed my time working with you and everyone else on our team at LMK. It’s rare to find a customer service role that offers as much opportunity to grow and learn and such a positive, inspiring team of people to grow and learn with.I’m particularly grateful for your guidance while I was considering furthering my education. Your support has meant so much to me.&nbsp;Please let me know if there’s anything I can do to help you find and train my replacement.Thanks, and best wishes,

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/html;charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">Dear All,</p><p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">I’m writing to resign from my position as <span style="font-weight: bold;">Web Developer</span>, effective August 20, 2019.</p><p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">I’ve recently d<span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">ecided to go back to school, and my program starts in early September</span>. I’m tendering my resignation now so that I can be as helpful as possible to you during the transition.</p><blockquote style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">I’ve truly enjoyed my time working with you and everyone else on our team at LMK. <span style="text-decoration-line: line-through;">It’s rare to find a customer service role that offers as much opportunity to grow</span> and learn and such a positive, inspiring team of people to grow and learn with.</blockquote><p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">I’m particularly grateful for your guidance while<span style="font-style: italic;"> I was considering furthering my education. </span>Your support has meant so much to me.&nbsp;</p><p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">Please let me know if there’s anything I can do to help you find and train my replacement.</p><p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.875rem 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-size: 17px;">Thanks, and best wishes,</p>

--AlternativeBoundaryString--

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="22366329_1711794525581687_2834310312601824228_n.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="22366329_1711794525581687_2834310312601824228_n.jpg"
Content-ID: <divya.deltatech@gmail.com>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCcUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAIAcAmcAFFJj
aVVyMDd0cHBaLTRWNkpodlZMHAIoAGJGQk1EMDEwMDBhYjYwMzAwMDA5NzEyMDAwMGM2MmEwMDAw
......
......
+QEQIiJ5HAAAnx/4H/k+v/sXI/TA/wDqP/Rx/wDiv+DjL/i//kOBgT6//WmTJ/jn/Bz/APe/+l9Y
aP8A+Ag3zx/+OZP/AMKfCcQ5e/2//ifdQ79XBRGr2Cvc/wD4lQYFLfP26xaoGV5P/wCJMCFF4C/8
+uEIDAz/2Q==

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: image/png;name="1561271605_apple-icon-60x60.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="1561271605_apple-icon-60x60.png"
Content-ID: <divya.deltatech@gmail.com>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/NlyAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAM
8klEQVRogc2b23Mc1Z3HP7/T3XOf0UgjybpL1lh3WQEvhkCCMQV4F8gSCCSQha192D9iH/Zh/4p9
......
......
/EkeG5vg5yvL/O8nH3N++TOubW7gq42+IbFHTvqeEK7DiDCaLzAyM88T48f56coy/37hPd789CM2
arXDJUfaxB8BJejO2uWjqaEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

--RelatedBoundaryString--

--MixedBoundaryString--
```

Once i encode and send the email
In Sender Part:

[image]

and in the receiving part, the mail is received as below screenshot

[image]

Plz help me out what is the issue with the email
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I copied and tried your code and got the same problem. What solved it for me is to actually change the `Content-ID` from attachment to attachment.

So instead of your raw string to be like:

```
--{$relatedBoundaryString}
Content-Type: {$mimetype};name=\"{$attachmentName}\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=\"{$attachmentName}\"
Content-ID: <{$to}>
```

You could try to transform the `Content-ID` to be unique for image, you could try to use your already defined variables like `attachmentName` or `filename`:

```
--{$relatedBoundaryString}
Content-Type: {$mimetype};name=\"{$attachmentName}\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=\"{$attachmentName}\"
Content-ID: <{$attachmentName}>
```